# Add special characther in notepad++/excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, notepad++

I Need to replace a string like this:
20211201153000

In date format like this

2021/12/01 15:30:00 (yyyy/MM/GG hh:mm:ss)

Any solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you should be able to do this with a fairly simple GREP search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)`
- Replace with: `$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\d\d\d\d)      # group 1, 4 digit. You can use \d{4}. year
(\d\d)          # group 2, 2 digit. month
(\d\d)          # group 3, 2 digit. day
(\d\d)          # group 4, 2 digit. hour
(\d\d)          # group 5, 2 digit. minute
(\d\d)          # group 6, 2 digit. second
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group1. year
/           # slash
$2          # content of group2 month
/           # slash
$3          # content of group 3. day
            # a space
$4          # content of group 4. hour
:           # colon
$5          # content of group 5. minute
:           # colon
$6          # content of group 6. second
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using Text function only

1] In `B2`, enter formula :

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000\/00\/00\ 00\:00\:00")
```

or,

2] Convert cell to Date format, in `B3` formula become:

```
=0+TEXT(A3,"0000\/00\/00\ 00\:00\:00")
```

Custom cell format to:  dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss

[image]

Comment: It is in NUMBER FORMAT

Answer (score 1):

with CONCAT and MID:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,{1,5,7,9,11,13},{4,2,2,2,2,2})&{"/","/"," ",":",":",""})
```

[image]

The above returns a string that looks like a date.  To create a true date use the double unary:

```
=--CONCAT(MID(A1,{1,5,7,9,11,13},{4,2,2,2,2,2})&{"/","/"," ",":",":",""})
```

And format the output as desired.

[image]